# How to reindex single level of pandas dataframe, leaving the rest as is?

Tags: python, pandas

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
    list('abcd'),
    list('efgh')
], names=['one', 'two'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.arange(len(mux))}, mux)
```

> ```
>          col
> one two     
> a   e      0
> b   f      1
> c   g      2
> d   h      3
> ```

I want

> ```
>          col
> one two     
> a   1      0
> b   2      1
> c   3      2
> d   4      3
> ```

using `np.arange`, and
keeping "two" as a second level index.

I can't find the correct way to do this, in place, without resetting everything.

I've tried variations on `reset_index`, `set_index`, `reindex`, but couldn't find how to do this.

---

Edit:

I probably don't understand multi index well enough to even create a proper reproducible...

[image]

This is my actual multi index:

```
1/0
1/1
...
1/11
2/0
2/1
...
2/7
```

And I want

```
1/0
1/1
...
1/11
2/12
2/13
...
2/19
```

`df.index.set_levels(levels=[1,2,3,4], level=1, inplace=True)`

works for the above example, but for this it just resets the index per level=0 index, and not as a whole.

Comment: for the multiindex, maybe try ``pd.DataFrame(df.to_dict(), index=df.index)`` and paste that for others to work with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1: Create a new index

The most straightforward I could think of is to just make a new MultiIndex, using as much information form the old as you can.  Here's new example data mimicking yours:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
    [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
    [0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3]
    ], names=['one', 'two'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.arange(len(mux))}, mux)
```

```
         col
one two     
1   0      0
    1      1
    2      2
    3      3
2   0      4
    1      5
    2      6
    3      7
3   0      8
    1      9
    2     10
    3     11
```

Create a new MultiIndex and assign:

```
new_levels = [df.index.get_level_values(0), range(1, len(df.index)+1)] # [original, updated]
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(new_levels, names=df.index.names)
df.index = idx
```

Now `df` is as expected:

```
         col
one two     
1   1      0
    2      1
    3      2
    4      3
2   5      4
    6      5
    7      6
    8      7
3   9      8
    10     9
    11    10
    12    11
```

#### Option 2: Use `set_levels` AND `set_codes`

You can use `set_levels` (as in my original answer, see below), but as OP pointed out that does not work alone in this case.  In addition to setting the levels (which is basically a list of possible values the index can take on), you also need to set the codes (`set_codes`) to update which index positions are associated with which member of the list of levels.  Which looks like this (again for my example data):

```
df.index.set_levels(levels=range(1,len(df.index)+1), level=1, inplace=True)
df.index.set_codes(codes=range(len(df.index)), level=1, inplace=True)
```

This is more opaque to me, so I prefer the first option.  For instance, the `codes` have to be values from `0` onward, as (I think) they are used as indices to select the appropriate values from `levels` (which can be inspected with `df.index.levels`), even though the actual values used (within `levels`) proceed from `1` onward.

---

*My original answer, which works for OP's original example, but wasn't working as I thought.  This approach would fail for my new example data without also updating the codes.*

You can use [`set_levels()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html):

```
df.index.set_levels(levels=[1,2,3,4], level=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I probably don't understand multi index well enough to even ask a question properly. Please see edit

Comment: @Gulzar I guess if you want the second level of the MultiIndex to continue counting regardless of the first level, could you do `levels=range(1, len(df.index)+1)` (following the above)?  I don't recognize your IDE, the slash `/` represents a multiindex?

Comment: the `/` represents the multi index. This is Pycharm pro. Trying with `levels=` like you stated doesn't make the second level keep counting, but rather resets the counter for every entry of `level=0`

Comment: @Gulzar see my update; thanks the comment, my original answer was not working as I expected (I also don't understand multiindex well :D)